# repair /service on encoder chips in smart car clutch actuator motor

Tags: transmission, clutch, smart-car, actuator

I am a DIYer trying to fix the clutch actuator motor on my Smart fortwo. The actuator has 3 components

A. the motor

B.the mechanical arm

C. the encoder.

A & B are good. component C is as shown.

[image: encoder from smart fortwo actuator motor]

QUESTION

1. What type of encoder is this?
2. How does it suppose to work?
3. Can i fix it by cleaning it? if not what is the fix?

Looking forward to your assistance. N.B I am not an Engineer - Not any! I have loads of the actuator DEAD!Tired of buying. and strongly believe there is a fix for them.

Answer (score 1):

These are most likely [SS461A hall effect sensors](https://eu.mouser.com/_/?Keyword=ss461a). They are about 2€ a piece. It may be worth a try to replace them. (They are available from other distributors as well.)

But first check if the magnet on the rotor isn't missing (or if the rotor has a slot instead.)